# use plain text as a Data Parameter in a POST request with Python

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm new to Python/rest API

[image]

the above screenshot is a sample POST request that running fine via 3rd party SandBox, and I want to be able run this POST Request via Python so I can do more personalization on it (e.g. run multiple taskid at one shot, output pre/post result, etc...):

**1- Issue Description:**

I'm using this script to make a POST request to a API. in this case, I want to pass the **plain text** (taskId = 125918) as a variable so can use it in the script, and can't make the same POST request with this plain text that highlighted in the above sample screenshot(taskId = 451).

```
taskId = 0
task = {(taskId, 'text/plain') : 125918}
r2 = requests.post(DisableSchedule, data = task, headers=headers)
```

**2- what have been tried:**

#1 "  tried below python script and gave an error : file "string", line unknown paraseError: no element found: line 1, coilmun 0

```
taskId = 0
task = {taskId : 125918}
r2 = requests.post(DisableSchedule, data = task, headers=headers)
```

or

```
r2 = requests.post(DisableSchedule, files = dict(taskId = 125918), headers=headers)
```

**3- How to make this request using the clear text as a variable in Python ?**

variable before the script, and I want to use this plain text variable in the POST request

> taskId = 125918

Answer (score 0):

use 'payload' in request body and it works now :

```
payload = "taskId=125918"
r2 = requests.request("POST",DisableSchedule, headers=headers, data = payload )
```